# How to process Kotlin code in Gradle KTS?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, code-generation, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a package in my app and I'd like to go over all classes in that package to then generate some JSON schema automatically.

I'd like to create a gradle task and with some sort of build-time dependency would allow me to do:

```kotlin
tasks.register("my fancy task") {

    doLast {
        "my.package.name".readKotlinFiles().classes.forEach { klass ->
            klass.properties["id"]... and do something here
        }
    }
}
```

How can you do such thing easily?

Comment: I guess you may try to make a custom Gradle plugin. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to achieve; my question is: how can I easily process my kotlin code (classes, members, functions) in my project from my custom gradle plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar, loading classes form the project, but not as a Gradle task or plugin but in Java application itself. To execute this logic as Gradle task / plugin I would do it in the following way:

1. First you generate jar package from your Kotlin project as a standard process of Kotlin-Gradle build.
2. As Gradle build is not a part of your project source code you have to load classes of the actual project with properly configured ClassLoader.
3. Then you can read those classes and generate the report.

Now that would translate into the pseudocode of a Gradle task:

```
tasks.register("processClasses") {

  dependsOn tasks.named("assemble") // generate jar
  doLast {

    // Initiate classloader of assembled project

    // Read target package from gradle properties or other kind of parameters
    
    // Get list of all classes under the specific package
    
    // Load the list of classes from classloader
    
    // Execute custom logic upon the list of classes
    
    // Generate report in specific format (JSON, YAML, HTML, ...)
  }
}
```

I tried to validate the logic and created a [POC as the following GitHub project](https://github.com/rivancic/gradle-process-classes). There are two flavors of build scripts:

- Groovy build script is in *master branch*
- [Kotlin build script version](https://github.com/rivancic/gradle-process-classes/tree/kotlin) is in *kotlin branch*. Note multiple
  aspects should be improved and adapted to the specific goal you have
  in mind (really curious actually). You are welcome to make any
  suggestions, fork the code, do changes..

Excerpt of the code below:

```kotlin
// Pack all the dependencies into jar
tasks.jar {
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath.map { configuration ->
        configuration.asFileTree.fold(files().asFileTree) { collection, file ->
            if (file.isDirectory) collection else collection.plus(zipTree(file))
        }
    })
}

val packageToProcess: String by project

tasks.register("processClasses") {

    group = "process"
    description = "Process classes form a specific package"
    dependsOn(tasks.named("assemble"))
    doLast {

        // Instantiate classloader from jar as you will need other dependencies for loading classes
        val file: File = project.projectDir.toPath().resolve(tasks.jar.get().archiveFile.get().toString()).toFile()
        println("Packaged Kotlin project jar file: $file")
        val classloader: ClassLoader = URLClassLoader(arrayOf(file.toURI().toURL()))

        // Iterate through all of the class files in the specified package
        val packageToScan: String = packageToProcess.replace(".", File.separator)
        val path: java.nio.file.Path = project.file("build/classes/kotlin/main/").toPath().resolve(packageToScan)
        val classesFromSpecificPackage = Files.walk(path)
            .filter {
                Files.isRegularFile(it)
            }
            .map {
                project.file("build/classes/kotlin/main/").toPath().relativize(it)
            }
            .map { it.toString().substring(0, it.toString().lastIndexOf(".")).replace(File.separator, ".") }
            .map {
                //println("Class = $it")  // print class if necessary before loading it
                classloader.loadClass(it)
            }

        // Do something with the classes form specific package
        // Now just basic information is printed directly to the console
        println("=======================================")
        println("Classes from package:  $packageToScan")
        println("")
        classesFromSpecificPackage.forEach {
            println("  Class: ${it.canonicalName}")
            val fields = it.declaredFields
            for (element in fields) {
                println("  - Declared field: $element")
            }
            println("")
        }
        println("=======================================")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer. I am using Gradle with the Kotlin DSL. I fear that what you just shared is groovy; when I tried to apply the `jar {}` block it says that such thing does not exist: Did you have to install something else to get it working? Thanks!

Comment: Let me see. It could be that some other plugin would be missing. I can try to create another project / branch with kotlin dsl.

Comment: Also, would there be a way of doing so without compiling the entire app (skipping creation of jar) ? As compilation can be slow. I'd just use the compiler's frontend output but I am missing indications there

Comment: I have updated the answer with the Kotlin version of the build script and also added the Kotlin version to the git repository. jar was not recognized as a task as you have to explicitly reference to the task in Kotlin through the tasks container. Now this is the way I would go about processing classes. To compile code and use compiled classes. I guess you need to execute this once in a while not in real time as you type the code. If you have performance issues with compiling whole project you can do processing only on a required module, or use Gradle build cache or other options..